# PHP post array and a curl submission

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have built a form submission consisting of about 90 values. The form needs to be submitted to another page that has a curl session which handles the last part.  My question is, when I submit that form, how do I access the $_Post[] data as a **whole array** so I can submit it as the curl post array?

need to get

```
<form name="send" action="process.php" method="post">
<input 1>
<inpit 2>
...
<input 90>
</form>
```

to

*process.php* :

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_Post[] );
```

Or is it as easy as putting $Post[]?

Comment: you can get the whole array with just $_post not $_post[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` value can be in a query-string format, `var1=value1&var2=value2...` or in an array format with the key being the field name, such as you have with `$_POST`.

You are currently using `$_POST[]` in your example; drop the `[]` and it should work fine:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```